# Update controller action - how to redirect to the index page after rendering json?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, react-on-rails

My app is built with ruby on rails on the backend, and react.js on the front end.

I can see in my rails console that I get the updated information from my http.patch request in rails, and it is received in rails, and now I am trying to adjust the update controller action to be able to redirect to the /donations page.

My routes for donations are as follows:

[Routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lawf0.png)

I am trying to figure out how I can redirect the routes so that when the PATCH occurs, it will send the user to the list of all donations, instead of staying on the /edit page which is what it is currently doing. My current update action is:

```
    def update
      if @donation.update(donation_params)
        render json: @donation
      else
        render json: @donation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end
```

I know this will not redirect at all, but I have tried to redirect_to donations_path and it will not work still. I tried to update the patch in the routes, to route to donations#index, but that doesn't work either... I am almost certain it is something to do with the update action, and/or, routes.rb, but this is my first time trying to patch an item and redirect - seems to be more complicated then I have ran into before... anyone know any suggestions to try?

Currently my routes for donations are back to square one:

```
    resources :donations, module: 'team'
```

looking for any suggestions on how to do something like this. Appreciate it in advance.

I expect that after I click save on my form, it passes the donation json back to rails, and then continues to redirect using rails routing, through the update action.

UPDATE: Added code to show the UseEffect, and handleSubmit functions, as well as the onClick call in the return to give more context to the client side operations.

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import { HTTP } from "../../api/resources";

    export default function DonationsEdit({donation: donationProps}) {
      const [donation, setDonation] = useState(null);
      const [saving, setSaving] = useState(false);
  
      useEffect(() => {
        if (!donation) {
          setDonation({
            ...donationProps,
            unit_cost: parseFloat(donationProps.unit_cost).toFixed(2)
          });
        }
      }, [donation, donationProps]);


    const handleSubmit = () => {
      setSaving(true)
      HTTP.patch(`/donations/${donation.id}`, {
      donation: donation
    }).then(response => {
      Alert.show("notice", "Donation Item Saved!");
      setDonation(response.data);
      setSaving(false);
    }).catch(e => {
      Alert.show("error", "Could not save. Try again or refresh.");
      setSaving(false);
    })
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleSubmit} name="button" className="btn btn-primary">
              {saving && <i className="fa fa-spinner-third fa-spin mr-2"></i>}
              Save
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: When you say you tried `redirect_to donations_path` and it "didn't work" what happened? Error? Nothing? Can you post the console logs when you tried that?

Comment: There was an error saying it can’t redirect to /donations/undefined, so it clearly doesn’t know when donation.id is being referred to … I tried passing it in as a variable to donations_path(@donations.id) but the problem still existed

Comment: I also tried redirect_to donation_path and the problem still persisted

Comment: You're thinking about this completely wrong. The server should either give the client a response body (JSON) or a redirect status code (300-308) with a `LOCATION` header. If you send both the client would redirect before it even actually does anything with the request body. What you want is probally just to do a client side redirect (`window.location = "/somewhere_else"`) or a simple transformation.

Comment: Usually in a API you respond to a successful PATCH request with `200 - OK` or `204 - NO CONTENT`. You rarely need to send JSON back as the client already knows what it updated and if it needs to refresh the data it can get it via `GET /thing/:id`. I think part of your problem here is that you're still thinking in terms of classical apps where the server side is responsible for steering the user around the application. In a SPA that responsibity is on the client side and the server is just responsible for delivering data.

Comment: Additionally sending a redirect in response to an XHR request doesn't cause the browser to redirect the window. It will either just do nothing or cause a new XHR request if you're using the options to follow redirects. This question won't be answerable without the relevant React code which is where you should actually be handling this.

Comment: Got it - thanks Max. I was thinking about doing it on the client side but thought it would be easier if I did it with rails routes. I will revision this with an attempt at the client side redirect and post the react code for further help if needed.

Comment: I added a snippet of the react code to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Max, I did the redirect on the client side and it worked using:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  setSaving(true)
  HTTP.patch(`/donations/${donation.id}`, {
    donation: donation
  }).then(response => {
    Alert.show("notice", "Donation Item Saved!");
    setDonation(response.data);
    setSaving(false);
    setTimeout(function() { window.location.href= '/donations';}, 1500);
  }).catch(e => {
    Alert.show("error", "Could not save. Try again or refresh.");
    setSaving(false);
  })
}
```